# App crashes on resuming question drafts

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, android-app, draft

Steps to reproduce :

- Click **Q** (Ask Question button)
- Add text to body
- Press back to exit from the add question view
- Click **Q** again
- Click **Resume**

The app crashes everytime.

Version: 0.1.19

..

Version: 0.1.21

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. When entering the post question screen the first time, is there any value automatically chosen for the site selector or is it blank?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi The value selected is the site on which I last posted (I think), MSO in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed in app version 0.1.24 coming out later today.

I wasn't able to get a 100% repro but I was still able to recreate the crash once in a while, I'm no longer seeing it and from what I changed I believe I fixed the race condition that was causing it, so if it is still happening after 0.1.24 please comment and I'll re-open the bug, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This the reason.

```
09-05 04:49:26.422: E/AndroidRuntime(937): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-05 04:49:26.422: E/AndroidRuntime(937): java.lang.NullPointerException: [v0.1.22] 
09-05 04:49:26.422: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.question.AskFragment$3.onClick(AskFragment.java:157)
```

Because there is no data avail to fetch in table `QuestionDraft`.

`new DraftTask(AskFragment.this.getActivity()).getQuestion();`

**returns null**

```
  public void onClick(DialogInterface paramAnonymousDialogInterface, int paramAnonymousInt)
  {
    PostDraft localPostDraft = new DraftTask(AskFragment.this.getActivity()).getQuestion();
    AskFragment.this.title.setText(localPostDraft.getTitle());
    . . .
    . . .
    . . .
    AskFragment.this.title.setSelection(AskFragment.this.title.getText().length());
  }
```

So, why is the developer trying to show us the null value???

Probably he/she forgot to edit the code on production version. Values are not pushed to the DB.

**saveDraft(false);** should be **saveDraft(true);**

```
    public void saveDraft()
    {
            saveDraft(false);
    }

    public void saveDraft(boolean paramBoolean)
    {
    if (paramBoolean)
    {
      String str2 = getSelectedSite();
      if (str2 == null)
        str2 = "";
      DatabaseManager.getManager(getActivity()).insertQuestionDraft(getTitle(), getBody(), getTags(), str2);
      return;
    }}
```

Chances are there that I might be wrong, since the below code follows without any condition, which inturn calls `insertQuestionDraft();`

```
new DraftTask(getActivity()).saveQuestion(getTitle(), getBody(), getTags(), str1);
```

I would like to know what went wrong, while insertion.

Comment: Great APKTool or APK2Gold skills :) The issue is that the PostDraft returns null when hitting "Resume" on the dialog, but the whole reason the dialog shows up is a check earlier in the code that says "if a draft exists in the database, show this", and I'm not able to reproduce the crash 100% so I think it's a race condition on writing/reading that I need to track down.

Comment: All credit goes to those devs. I am able to reproduce it every time. My `QuestionDraft` remains empty, but `AnswerDraft` gets updated. Probably we have clean Uninstall and retry. Thought `QuestionDraft` is empty, am shown with dialog for resuming drafts as expected, on click of resume it crashes.