# Questions submitted in android app turns into "How to simulate session cookies in mobile sessions?"

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I tried to upload this question:

> [image]

And got this when I hit submit?

> [image]

Steps to reproduce:

1. Submit a question.

Using CyanogenMod 10.2 (Android 4.3)

Comment: What version of the app are you using?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Should be the latest one.

Comment: mind double checking?

Comment: Open up the settings app on your phone, go to "Manage Applications" and click on Stack Exchange. It should be a number starting with 0 :)

Comment: Thought so! 0.1.19 should be in the Play Store right now which should fix this.

Comment: Now I'm getting a StackExchange has Stopped when resuming continued draft.

Comment: That is a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195119/app-crashes-on-resuming-question-drafts so I'm going to mark this as invalid.

Comment: I'm bumping this because despite the answer, this is not fixed. It just happened to me. Seems to happen on bad connections.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was fixed in app version 0.1.19 which came out yesterday.

Comment: I see this "session cookie" message often when I suggest edits. I have the latest version of the app. OnePlus One, Marshmallow stock. Should I ask a separate question on site for this?

Comment: @NVZ [already reported again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291544/whenever-there-is-a-poor-internet-connection-the-preview-section-of-ask-questi), I don't know what Kasra fixed, but over the years the fix just vanished.

Comment: @ShadowWizard it has happened to me a few more times since my last comment. I always stay on the latest version.

Comment: This is still happening.