# Whenever there is a poor Internet connection, the preview section of 'ask question' shows this!

Tags: bug, android-app

I have faced this problem many times on a slow connection or a Wi-Fi network with poor signal strength. The preview section of the 'ask question' seems to show a question by default which I have never asked.

The screenshot of the problem is given below.

> [image: The Bug]

This problem has annoyed me many times and I suppose that this is a bug so if anyone else faces the same please let me know, and help me.

- App version: 1.0.89
- Device manufacturer: LENOVO
- Device model: Lenovo A2020a40
- OS version: 5.1.1 (A2020a40_USR_S179_1606221943_Q8909_ROW)

Comment: [This has happened before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195143/questions-submitted-in-android-app-turns-into-how-to-simulate-session-cookies-i), was "fixed" and fix is broken.

Comment: Surely my app is more recent than ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195146/352209 ) the one mentioned here. They say that they have fixed it in version 0.1.19 while I am using version 1.0.89.

Comment: I know, like I said, whatever was fixed is now broken again. Just linking to the old report in case one day someone will want to fix it.

Comment: I think SE management does not think the android app deserves their attention.

Comment: @NVZ same for iOS app -- there's a bug that is never fixed for over a year

Comment: @NVZ both apps are officially on hold for a long time now. Stack Exchange spends its resources on other things, currently Teams.